# How to identify and fix Missing blocks reported by Ambari for the NameNode?

Tags: hadoop

Ambari is generating an alert `NameNode Blocks Health: Total Blocks:[38252543], Missing Blocks:[2]`. No further information.

I've run `hdfs fsck /` which is reporting the entire filesystem as healthy. I've run `hdfs dfsadmin -report` which reports that there are two missing blocks, but does not give details.

How do I find these missing blocks and thence fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I've observed a similar kind of reporting my setup today (CentOS 7.3, HDP 2.5.3, Ambari 2.4.2).

The files with missing blocks I were able to find via:

```
hdfs fsck / | grep -i 'miss' 
hdfs fsck / | grep 'miss' | cut -d ":" -f 1
hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

and fixing them with:

```
hdfs dfs -setrep 3 <fileName>
```

Comment: thank you. It's been a while but I believe I ended up running the same command to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can find no.of corrupted and missing blocks with below command

```
hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks
```